# Find documents with sub-documents matching both of two (or more) properties

Tags: node.js, mongodb, subdocument

In Node with Mongoose I want to find an object in the collection `Content`. It has a list of sub-documents called `users` which has the properties `stream`, `user` and `added`. I do this to get all documents with a certain user's `_id` property in there `users.user` field.

```
Content.find( { 'users.user': user._id } ).sort( { 'users.added': -1 } )
```

This seems to work (although I'm unsure if `.sort` is really working here. However, I want to match *two* fields, like this:

```
Content.find( { 'users.user': user._id, 'users.stream': stream } } ).sort( { 'users.added': -1 } )
```

That does not seem to work. What is the right way to do this?

---

Here is a sample document

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("551c6b37859e51fb9e9fde83"),
    "url" : "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f9v_XN7Wxh8",
    "title" : "Playing Games in 360°",
    "date" : "2015-03-10T00:19:53.000Z",
    "author" : "Econael",
    "description" : "Blinky is a proof of concept of enhanced peripheral vision in video games, showcasing different kinds of lens projections in Quake (a mod of Fisheye Quake, using the TyrQuake engine).\n\nDemo and additional info here:\nhttps://github.com/shaunlebron/blinky\n\nThanks to @shaunlebron for making this very interesting proof of concept!\n\nSubscribe: http://www.youtube.com/subscription_center?add_user=econaelgaming\nTwitter: https://twitter.com/EconaelGaming",
    "duration" : 442,
    "likes" : 516,
    "dislikes" : 13,
    "views" : 65568,
    "users" : [ 
        {
            "user" : "54f6688c55407c0300b883f2",
            "added" : 1427925815190,
            "_id" : ObjectId("551c6b37859e51fb9e9fde84"),
            "tags" : []
        }
    ],
    "images" : [ 
        {
            "hash" : "1ab544648d7dff6e15826cda7a170ddb",
            "thumb" : "...",
            "orig" : "..."
        }
    ],
    "tags" : [],
    "__v" : 0
}
```

Comment: Can you please post a sample document in your collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use $elemMatch operator to specify multiple criteria on an array of embedded documents:

```
Content.find({"users": {$elemMatch: {"user": user.id, "stream": stream}}});
```

Comment: Thanks. Actually I had tried this, but the problem ended up being a typo in my model. Thanks for confirming this, though.